# Output User firstname lastname as link to profile in Drupal 7 views

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, profiles

In Drupal 7, I'm trying to output a list of users related to a node in a view, which I've got working fine.

However, the only way to link to the user profile is to use the user:name field in views, which gives me the markup

```
<a href="/users/username">username</a>.
```

I've got two additional profile fields, user:Firstname and user:Lastname, but can't see to find a way to do this:

```
<a href="/users/username">[user:firstname] [user:lastname]</a>
```

as each time I try and rewrite the output of the link, it refuses to work; user:url doesn't exist as option in my views UI (which contains the link I need according to Devel).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it. But my educated guess is that the easiest solution for you would be to look at the [realname](http://drupal.org/project/realname) module, which should do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I guess I could use another module, but it seems insane considering I've already seemingly got the values there, but can't output them..